# How to acces pointer in a structure

Tags: c, arrays, struct

This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct pers
{
    int age;
    char *name;
    float height;
}Person;

void read(Person p[], int *nr) // an array of persons, and nr is the number of persons
{
    scanf("%d", nr);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < *nr; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &p[i].age);
        p[i].name = calloc(100, sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", p[i].name);
        scanf("%f", &p[i].height);  
    }
}

int main()
{
    int nr;
    Person p[100];
    int i;
    read(p, &nr);
    for(i = 0; i < nr; i++)
    {   
        printf("%d\n", p[i].age);
        printf("%s\n", p[i].name);
        printf("%f\n", p[i].height);
    }
return 0;
}
```

I don't know why this not stocate well the data . How can i do with pointers or anything else, to have acces to age and height and also to the *name

If i try only with age and height the code works, but when i add the name, it stucks.

this is my input

```
3 // numbers of persons
23 // age
John Smith //firstname + lastname         //1person
182.5 //height
18
Mat Plow                                  //2person
152.6
56
Alex Grim                                 //3person
172
```

Any ideas?

i think i might use gets and with some pointer, but i don't know how :D

Thank you !

Comment: do you write `#include <stdlib.h>` ? also show your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf(" %[^\n]s", p[i].name);`

This is what works for me !

Answer (score 2):

Because there is nothing wrong with your code, there must be something wrong with your scanf input specification. Check/read the input format specifier documentation. For '%s' it says: "String, up to first white-space character (space, tab or newline)" so if name is "Firstname Lastname" it will only read "Firstname".

Also, you can add debug statements to see what has been read so-far, or you can use a debugger to step through the code to see what happens. A scanf-guru can tell you right away what's wrong; all others must read the documentation.

Comment: yes, this is my problem, but how can i read the entire name, like `FirstName LastName` ?

Comment: Read the documentation of format specification. It is clearly documented how to do that.

Answer (score -2):

Change your `scanf` call to this:

```
scanf("%s\n", p[i].name);
```

Please note the `\n` added.

Comment: don't tell me this is the single problem , because i go crazy :)))

Comment: @user3582615 don't do this

Comment: this works only if i want to read a word, if there are 2 the code crashes